# Работа с файлами в C

Tags: c, файлы, fopen

Есть ли в `<stdio.h>` функции для записи и чтения на определённой строке файла?

Например, есть поток с файлом `name.txt`, как мне записать значение массива

```
char str[] = "Какая-либо информация";
```

в строку файла под номером `2` так, чтобы потом можно было обратиться к строке под этим номером и изъять информацию?

Comment: текст находиться в массиве на определённых ячейках памяти или если на жёстком диске на определённом секторе и определённом индексе. Смещение информации реализуется путём полного считывания файла, вручную подсчитывая места где находятся новые строки и потом уже **самостоятельного** записывания в новое место памяти/нового файла.

Comment: @AlexGlebe то есть, нужно считывать кол-во `\n`, тем самым определяя кол-во строк?

Comment: в винде '\r\n' , в старом маке '\r' , в линуксе '\n'

Comment: @AlexGlebe понял, спасибо

Comment: В текстовом режиме *в винде '\r\n' , в старом маке '\r' , в линуксе '\n'* — все превращаются просто в `\n`...

Comment: @Harry спасибо за уточнение